# Calculating differences between two sheets (efficiency issue)

Tags: microsoft-excel, performance, vba, powerpivot

Current setup to compare history on AR Financial Data:
-Two excel sheets with identical headers Range: `A1 to AL250,000`
-On one of the sheets, we added 13 Columns, which have equations doing comparisons between Sheet1 and Sheet2.
**Equation 1:** `VLOOKUP` from Sheet1 to Sheet2 (Input: Invoice #, Output: Current balance)
**Equation 2:** If statements all on Sheet1 that all reference the `VLOOKUP` result to overdue aging buckets

This means I am currenty calculating 3.25 MIL equations (*13 Col X 250,000 Rows*). As a result, the excel is extremely slow (Current file size: **124MB**).

I have turned off auto-calculate but the excel still gives me problems to work with as it is constantly freezing. Is this data just too big for excel?

Assuming that I am limited to MSO, is there a better way to do this? Pivot? Power Pivot? Data Link? Macro to calculate and paste values as text? Quit my job?

Simply looking for a more experienced excel user to give input on most efficient route to pursue, not how to implement whichever route.

Comment: Using this amount of data will cause massive lag. Excel is not built to handle this kind of data size. Your best alternative is a database program. You can use Access or make an XML based database yourself.

Comment: Since the Excel is getting slower or sometimes hang (freeze) means problem with Memory & Processor,,, better add some RAM sticks or upgrade the system.

Comment: Are you doing this in a macro or manually? Is the Excel file .xls or .xlsx?

Comment: For Excel, "too much" is mostly a function of your available system resources. Using a modern but by no means high-powered computer a former CFO I supported regularly performed Pivot Table actions and macros and formulas on a table with over 900k rows of data and hundreds of columns. The computer had 8GB of RAM and while the sheet wasn't a speed demon, it never crashed and was quite capable.

Comment: I’m going to assume it’s **slsx** (file is on work computer and Its the weeeeeekend). Not running any macros on this file - do you think it is worth while to do the calculations in a macro to clear the formulas from the sheet. Unfortunately I’m limited by a work computer and since it’s sensitive financial data, I am not allowed to move the file off the local network. I have a much more powerful computer at home but I cannot use it here  :/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can export your data on a less detailed level. For instace, not list every transaction, but only the sums of each invoice or customer, then use the 13 columns with formulas on the lesser list.

Maybe create a function to dig into the details of a single customer in a separate tab.

If you cant reduce the data size, you can try doing some cleaning up in your formulas to make them faster. I experienced a substantial improvement by writing an if-statement with True being an easy formula and false being a more demanding formula.

[=IF(A1<>1,"",..heavy formula..)]
insead of
[=IF(A1=1,..heavy formula..,"")]

Try running calculations by adding one column of formulas at a time to identify which ones are slowing you down the most.

Good luck to you :)